# Stirling numbers of first kind

Tags: stirling-numbers

Let $\sigma=\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \cdot \cdot \cdot \sigma_n \in S_n$ which means a permutation of the elements $1,2,...,n$. $\sigma_j$ is called a left-right maximum of $ \sigma$ if $\sigma_k <\sigma_j$ for all $k<j$. $a_{n,k}$ is the number of permutations in $S_n$ with exactly $k$ left right maxima. I have to show that
$a_{n,k}=\frac{n!}{k!}[z^n](\log\frac{1}{1-z})^k$.

I know that these are the Stirling numbers of first kind, but I have no idea how to proove it. Do you have ideas? Please help me.

Comment: where does this $z$ come from ?

Comment: @MJ73550 it means the coefficient of $z^n$ of $ f(z)$

Comment: sorry for I am not familiar with this kind of maths, what $f$ is supposed to be ?

Comment: a sequence can be transformed into a formal power series, or z -transform, f(z) and $\left[ {z^{\,n} } \right]f(z)$ gives you back the $n$-th element of the sequence, whose transform is f(z).
 see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series

Comment: @Mathfreak I am not sure to grasp exactly the meaning of your definition. it seems to me that the permutation with exactly $k$ right maxima is the one which is strictly increasing till position $k$, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Ask how we  can obtain a permutation on  $[n+1]$ having $k$ left-right
maxima from a permutation on $[n]$ by incrementing all elements of the
latter and  adding a  smallest element, one.   A permutation  on $[n]$
having  $k-1$ maxima  produces  a permutation  on  $[n+1]$ having  $k$
maxima if we  place the smallest element in  front, for a contribution
of $\left[n\atop  k-1\right]$ (we  gain a maximum  from the  new first
element). On the other hand  if we place the smallest element anywhere
else ($n$ possibilities)  in a permutation on $[n]$  having $k$ maxima
it does  not affect the these,  for a contribution  of $n \left[n\atop
k\right].$ This yields the recurrence

$$\left[n+1\atop k\right] =
\left[n\atop k-1\right] +  n \left[n\atop k\right]$$

which is the Stirling number recurrence.